# R Knitr functionalities missing

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

On the following image, we can see the three buttons on the far right.
[image: Desired Knitr Functionalities]

On the link below, the three buttons on the far right disappear.
[image: Problem]

Could you help me solve this issue?

Comment: You need to rename the chunks - edit the second image to say something like ````{r 2}````

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work. I have done so and run it. There are also other chunks in which I didn't input {r 2}, {r 3} and so on, but those chunks have those functionalities.

Comment: What is your RStudio version?